# Angularjs assigning value to ng-model using ng-init

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I have following issue which seems easy and should work but is not.

In my code I have input

```
 <input type="text"  ng-model="c.Id"  ng-init="c.Id={{pId}}"/>
```

When I look at the DOM using firebug tool I see the value

```
 <input type="text"  ng-model="c.Id"  ng-init="c.Id=6"/>
```

But it wont display 6 in the input box neither I can access it using #scope. 
Please let me know what is wrong here and how to fix it so that ng-model can have from ng-init. 
Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Get rid of the braces in the expression so that it will evaluate pId directly from the scope

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="c.Id"  ng-init="c.Id=pId"/>
```

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/OaKnDNRSVoK18IbpDlTk?p=preview)

Answer (score 5):

`ng-init`takes an expression and therefore you do not need the curly braces:

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="c.Id"  ng-init="c.Id=pId"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assigning the value to ng-model using ng-value

```
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="inputPrice" />
   <input type="text" ng-model="newPrice" ng-value="newPrice=inputPrice" />
```